# Installing grass extension through shell script

Tags: grass-gis, extensions, shell

I wanted to install an GRASS extension through a shell script but, upon execution it says:

> You don't have permission to install extension to . Try to run g. extension with administration rights (su or sudo)
>   sudo : : command not found

That been said I tried to execute this line of code:

`add_on="$(g.extension extension=i.segment.uspo operation=add)"
 sudo "$add_on"`

I know that I've done something wrong, but I don't know what.

---

Grass Version: Grass 7.0

Linux dist: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Which operating system do you use? And, which GRASS GIS version? Please add this to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main problems were two.

1) As a newbie I didn't know that I had to install "grass-dev" and I solved it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install grass-dev
```

2) It was my mistake that I forgot to change the ownership for my Grass folder by typing:

```
sudo chown -R $usern $EXT_ADDONS
```

where

> $usern

is username:group and

> $EXT_ADDONS

is the Grass directory

and in case there is an error where a file cannot be downloaded for whatever reason (i.e /var/cache/apt/archives/grass-dev_7.0.5-1~xenial1_amd64.deb) you can fix it by typing

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite 'file'
```

in the case of our paradigm

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/grass-dev_7.0.5-1~xenial1_amd64.deb
```

which isn't usually the best idea, but it will make grass-dev work

Answer (score 1):

I was successful installing add-ons via the command line with:

```
 grass -text -c EPSG:4326 --exec g.extension extension=i.segment.uspo operation=add
```

Comment: This is a good answer, although it won't work as is. The text flag should be `--text` and, the location and mapset need to be set in advance. This can be circumvented with the `--tmp-mapset` flag, i.e.:

`grass --tmp-mapset --exec g.extension extension=i.segment.uspo operation=add`